# Onclick event for a link to send an ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

If you have a word on a page that you want to capture an onclick event and send an ajax request from this, how do you do that?

Comment: I suggest using javascript.

Comment: [**You do some research first.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onclick) [**What can I ask on SO?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: By writing code that 1. recognises click events on that specific section of the page, then 2. sends an AJAX request. Depending on your skill with JavaScript neither of those is particularly difficult, and both are extremely well documented both here and elsewhere on the Internet. As it stands your question is far too broad to meet SO's standards; take a look at the [faq].

Answer (score 2):

[**jQuery**](http://jquery.com) makes this easy!

### HTML

```
<div>Here's the <span class="myLink">word</span></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*onclick event*/
    $(".myLink").click(function() {
        /* The AJAX call*/
        $.post('http://myurl.com/',{ 'my' : 'data'},function(response) {
            //do something with the result
        });
    });
});
```